# Обработка видеопотока из HTML<img> при помощи C++/Qt

Tags: html, c++, qt

**Имеем:** ESP32-CAM, локальный веб сервер (из стандартных примеров для данного модуля), который генерирует DOM:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px; background: #0e0e0e;">
    <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;" src="http://192.168.1.105:81/stream">
  </body>
</html>
```

Как я понял (возможно не верно, поправьте кто знает) - сервер выкидывает кадры в `<img>` тэг с максимально возможной частотой (fps), обновляется лишь содержимое тэга, когда весь DOM - остаётся статичным (по принципу ajax). Не совсем понятно как это реализовано, ведь нет ни скриптов ни POST/GET запросов (по крайней мере из браузера этого не видно). Возможно, здесь как-то замешано UDP-HTTP межпротокольное взаимодействие, может ли кто-нибудь посоветовать статьи/литературу по теме?

**Вопрос:** Как при помощи C++/Qt можно получить это самый стрим (в виде последовательности кадров или ByteArray). Пробовал QWebSockets, но получал лишь HTML DOM типа `QString`, в то время как тег `<img>` был пуст. Буду благодарен за любой совет или направление в какую сторону копать.

Comment: обычный себе get запрос на http://192.168.1.105:81/stream

Comment: @user7860670, Получаю String (DOM) без какой-либо информации о кадре

Comment: т.е. как это? по любому адресу отдается эта страница?

Comment: @user7860670, использую для GET-запроса QNetworkAccessManager::get(const QNetworkRequest &request), дерево он возвращает отлично, но вместо стрима (или хотя бы кадра) я получаю пустую строку (пустой массив)